# Importing module required by module

Tags: python

I'm writing a web app for a college assignment using Python/Flask and, to keep my app.py file neat, I have a  function to query a DB stored in another file. This function uses pymysql and json modules and I can't manage to load these in a way that makes it work - I keep getting an attribute error saying pymysql is not defined.

I've tried putting import statements in my module file (DBjson.py), within the function contained in my module, and within app.py. This is my module code:

```
def fetchFromDB(host,port,dbname,user,password,query,jsonString=False):
    import pymysql # these import statements are in the function in this example - one of several places I've tried them!  
    import json
    conn = pymysql.connect(host, user=user,port=port, passwd=password, db=dbname)
    cursorObject = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

    with cursorObject as cursor:
        cursor.execute(query)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        conn.close()

    if jsonString == True:
        try:
            for i in range(len(result)):
                result[i]['dateTime'] = result[i]['dateTime'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
    except:
        pass
    result = json.dumps(result)


    return result
```

And the route from my app.py:

```
import pymysql
import json


@app.route('/')
def index():
    wds = DBjson.fetchFromDB(host,port,dbname,user,password,weatherQuery)
    bds = DBjson.fetchFromDB(host,port,dbname,user,password,bikesQuery)
    return render_template('weatherDateTime.html', wds=wds, bds=bds)
```

Any help on how to make this work?

Thanks!

edit - I wrote a test script from which I can load my module and run my function no problem - I have my import statements at the start of the DBjson.py module file and outside of the function. Is this some quirk of Flask/scoping that I don't know about?

PS - Thanks for all the replies so far

```
import DBjson


query = "SELECT * FROM dublinBikesInfo WHERE dateTime LIKE (SELECT MAX(datetime) FROM dublinBikesInfo);"




#login details for AWS RDS DB
host="xyza"
port=3306
dbname="xyza"
user="xyza"
password="xyza"

a = DBjson.fetchFromDB(host,port,dbname,user,password,query)

print(a)
```

Comment: this might be a silly question, but are you sure you have pymysql installed. Is the error during the import or after the import if already done?

Comment: No silly questions, just silly programmers :) pymysql is installed, it's working fine in other contexts. I'm starting to think that if I look at this after a good night's sleep I'll see what's wrong...

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Try importing 'pymysql' at the top of DBjson.py (outside of any functions).

Comment: I already have. I've a feeling I'll come back to this and I'll look somewhere else and figure it out. Thanks for the suggestion, always appreciated :)

Comment: LeKhan9 - I'm now importing pymysql at the top of DBjson.py - it works fine in a test script I wrote (included at the bottom of my original post not) but still won't work in flask, the same NameError: pymysql not defined. Arg!

Comment: and you're also importing DBjson at the top of app.py?

Comment: It turned out to be an idiot level error on my part, I edited the wrong copy of the module...D'oh! Sorry lads

Answer (score 0):

Hi in your code there is a indent error all the statements has to be inside of the function/method that you have created ex.

```
`def method():
        #code here`
```

And also try to import the library’s before defining a function/method in the beginning of the page is also good!!

In your scenario please put all the function/method related statements inside of the function/method!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply - my code is correctly indented in my script, I just messed up putting it in here - I'll see if I can edit it now :)

Comment: Okay import packages at the beginning of the code. In the directory make sure you don’t have a file called pymysql.py

Answer (score 0):

Python is very unforgiving about indentation. Your module code isn't indented correctly.

The proper way to do this, would be:

```
def Function():
      #your code indented in here
```